# iOS graphics engines

Tags: ios, graphics, opengl-es

I am new to iOS programming and am interested in working with images. Basically, I want to be able to obtain the (0,255) and RGB tuples of every pixel in a given image. What would be the best way of doing this? Would I need to use Open GL, or something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to work with images, get a copy of Apple's 'Quartz 2D Programming Guide'. If you want even more detailed how-to, get a copy of the "Programming with Quartz" book on Amazon (its says Mac in the title as it predates iOS).

Essentially you are going to take images, draw them into bit map contexts, then determine the rgba layout by querying the image.

If you want to use system resources to assist you in making certain types of changes to images, there is a OSX framework recently moved to iOS called the Accelerate Framework. and it has a lot of functions in it for image manipulation (vImage).

For reading and writing images to the file system look at Apple's 'Image I/O Guide'. For advanced filtering there is Core Image, which allows you to apply filters to images.

EDIT: If you have any interest in really fast accellerated code that uses the GPU to perform some sophisticated filtering, you can checkout Brad Larson's [GPU Image](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) project on github.

Comment: There's also this little hobby project of mine: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Comment: @BradLarson, how could I have ever forgotten it!